# How to override an implicit value?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-2.11

Suppose I have the code:

```
class A(implicit s:String = "foo"){println(s)}

object X {
   implicit val s1 = "hello"
}
object Y {
   import X._
   // do something with X
   implicit val s2 = "hi"
   val a = new A
}
```

I get the error:

```
<console>:14: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value s2 in object Y of type => String
 and value s1 in object X of type => String
 match expected type String
           val a = new A
```

Is there any way I can tell Scala to use the value `s2` in `Y`? 
(if I rename `s2` to `s1`, it works as expected but that is not what I want).

Another solution is to not do `import X._`, again something I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another thing you can do is to import everything but `s1`: `import X.{s1 => _, _}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Probably the best one till now.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the other answer that explicitly providing the implicit in these types of situations is preferred, but if you insist on wanting to 'downgrade' the other implicit so it's no longer treated as an implicit then it is actually possible:

```
class A(implicit s:String = "foo"){println(s)}

object X {
  implicit val s1 = "hello"
}
object Y {
  import X._
  val s1 = X.s1 //downgrade to non-implicit

  // do something with X
  implicit val s2 = "hi"
  val a = new A
}
```

Again, this is a bit hackish, but it works.

Comment: Agree.. A bit hackish but does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
new A()(s2)
```

This should override the implicit parameter through er explicitly providing it.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using the implicit parameter. I have `new A` in several places and I'd rather just remove the implicit then.

Comment: @Jus12 I just don't see how you are going to be able to keep the wildcard import and not override the explicit at least once...

Comment: Using an `implicit` for something small and objective like `strings` does not make sense in the first place.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I agree. The String is just for the sake of example. In my actual code its quite a complex object.

Comment: @Jus12 What happens if you name s2 the same as s1? Just out of curiosity

Comment: And you have multiple instances of that complex object in scope. `Implicits` generally make sense for `Helper-functions`, `typeclass abstract evidences` such as `Monads` or large and meant to be reused large objects like `ActorSystem`.

Comment: @Others: When I use `s1`, the behaviour is what I want and expected: It overrides the old one. However, I don't want the names to be the same due to other reasons.